# Passing a vector with different types as initializer list to function

Tags: c++, vector, c++17, initializer-list

I have this **none working** code which should demonstrate what I want to achieve:

```
class Member
{
    const char * someText;
    union Parameter
    {
        const char * ptrParameter;
        double       doubleParameter;
        uint         uintParameter;
    };
};

class MyClass
{
    auto foo( std::vector<Member> & ) -> void;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass instance;

    instance.foo( 
        {
            { "SomeText", "TextParameter" },
            { "SomeDouble", 3.14159 },
            { "SomeUint",   32767 }
        }
                );
}
```

---

**What I want to achieve:**

1. `MyClass::foo` expects a `std::vector<Member>` as parameter.
2. This vector should be passed directly from an initializer list.
3. The second parameter for `Member` can have different types which is here expressed *with* `union Parameter`.
4. How can I *detect* in `MyClass::foo` which types have been passed?
5. The types in `union Parameter` can be only these 3 as described.

I was trying a lot but no way I had success due to the fact I am a C++ beginner.

---

**I am using C++17 - Boost is not an option.** How can be this achieved?

Comment: C++ unions don't track which member is active. There is no way to recover that information after the fact. Would [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) work for you as an alternative?

Comment: @hvd **YES**, I have to check it out first. `union` is here just a place holder for what I want to achieve. What ever meats the requirement I will use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get pretty close with [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
class Member
{
    const char * someText;
    std::variant<const char *, double, unsigned int> parameter;
};
```

But you'll need a few additional changes to allow the type of initialisation you want:

- The fields need to be `public` to allow aggregate initialisation (the compiler's built-in initialisation from `{ a, b }`), but `class` types have `private` fields by default. In this case, I would change `class` to `struct`.
- `auto foo( std::vector<Member> & ) -> void` takes `std::vector<Member>` by lvalue reference, but you want to allow calling this with a temporary vector. In that case, I would not use a reference. I would take a `std::vector<Member>` by value.
- `{ "SomeUint", 32767 }` will not be a valid initialiser because `32767` has type `signed int`. It can be converted to both `double` and `unsigned int` and the compiler will not be able to figure out which one you want. You can write `32767u` to have a constant of type `unsigned int`. (I'm assuming that's what your `uint` is a typedef for.)

> How can I *detect* in `MyClass::foo` which types have been passed?

The best way for that depends on the reason you're doing it. If you'd like to execute different code based on the value being held, use [`visit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit). If you'd like to conditionally execute code for one type only, use [`get_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get_if). If you'd just like to check, but do nothing with the value itself, use either [`index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/index) or [`holds_alternative`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/holds_alternative).

Comment: Yep, `std::variant` and in my case together with `std::get_if` is the solution. +1! Thx

Comment: Your statement regarding `uint` was correct. Due to the fact in my project this parameter is  a variable then the compiler can assign the value and compile it without an error. Using a constant fails - I had to append the  `u`.